# ContributionDashboard correct amount not equal CiviReport

Tags: civicontribute

Stripe.com shows we received a donation of $15.
It correctly shows on the Civi Contribution Dashboard.
When we run Civi Report, the amount shows up as $30.
We have many cases when the report and the dashboard give the correct results. This is the first time when the amounts do not agree.  Anybody know what is wrong?
[image]

Comment: can you add a screenshot of the expanded section below the $15 , and/or of the 'View' version of that contribution

Comment: I found that removing Donor Phone from the columns stops the report showing a double amount.
Asking for the Donor Phone adds the following to the query
  LEFT JOIN civicrm_phone phone_civireport
             ON contact_civireport.id = phone_civireport.contact_id AND
                phone_civireport.is_primary = 1

Comment: I found that the donor had two home phone numbers in her contact info. Removing the second home phone, resulted in the amount not being doubled.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution -> copy/paste it into an answer (you can answer your own question)

Comment: only one of those phones should have been 'is_primary' so something with that report may be off

Answer (score 1):

I found that the donor had two home phone numbers in her contact info. Removing the second home phone, resulted in the amount not being doubled.